# What is the difference between inconsistent analysis and dirty reads?

Tags: sql

I am a newbie at SQL and prepering for a test. I would like to know what the difference is between 'dirty reads' and 'inconsistent analysis'. These are to do with the integrity of the table. I googled and found some answers but can't seem to differentiate the two. This is what I've gathered and they both pretty much have the same meaning:
Dirty Read/Inconsistent Analysis: if transaction A starts and changes a value and transaction B reads this value before transaction A can commit/rollback then there's a possibilty of a false value being entered since A may have rollbacked but B read a invalid value.

If someone can point the difference between the two then that would be great :)

Comment: Can you expand what you mean by 'inconsistent analysis', please.

Answer (score 1):

Both of them describe situations where a previous transaction is changing the data that a second transaction is reading. However,

> in inconsistent analysis, the data read by the second transaction **was committed by the transaction that made the change**, unlike dirty read. Also, inconsistent analysis involves multiple reads (two or more) of the same row and each time the information is changed by another transaction, thus producing different results each time, and hence **inconsistent**.

In the case of dirty read, the first transaction has not committed the transaction yet, and hence the data fetched by the second transaction may or may not be the most latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take two transactions, T1 and T2

Than main difference is that in dirty read, the error happens because T1 modified a value failed complete, so was rolled back and then T2 reads the value before it is rolled back. However, with inconsistent analysis, T1 actually completes, yet the value read by T2 is incorrect because the T1 further modifies it (In another operation within the same T1) before completion, causing T2 to use a wrong value in its transaction.